# L equivalence strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $L$ be the language consisting of all strings in $(a+b)^*$ that have an even number of letters and do not have $aaba$ as a substring.

Into how many $L$-equivalence classes is $(a+b)^*$ divided?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: According to the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), the number of $L$-equivalence classes is the same as the number of states in the minimal DFA that recognizes $L$. Find a DFA that recognizes $L$, and then minimize it.